# Meaningful interpretation of the integral of a cumulative prob. Function?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I solved a maximization problem in which the maximizing value of $x$ is equal to 
$$\int_0^c F(s)ds$$

Where $F(s)$ is the **cumulative** probability distribution of a random variable $Y$.

---

We all know what integrating over the **density** function means, but is there a meaningful interpretation of integratjng over a **cumulative** distribution function?

Ps. I dont necessarily have any reason to believe that there **has** to be a meaningful interpretation.

Comment: For every $s$, $$F(s)=P(X\leqslant s)=\int_\Omega\mathbf 1_{X\leqslant s}\,dP$$ hence $$\int_0^cF(s)\,ds=\int_\Omega\int_0^c\mathbf 1_{X\leqslant s}\,ds\,dP$$ where $$\int_\mathbb R\mathbf 1_{X\leqslant s}\,\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant s\leqslant c}\,ds=\int_\mathbb R\mathbf 1_{\max(X,0)\leqslant s\leqslant c}\,ds=\max(0,c-\max(X,0))$$ Thus, for every $c\geqslant0$, $$\int_0^cF(s)\,ds=c\,P(X\leqslant0)+E(c-X;0<X\leqslant c)$$

Comment: It's hard for me to follow this.

Comment: It's hard for me to follow why it's hard for you to follow this if you do not say why it's hard for you to follow it.